# Regex replace (sed or perl) with variable capture

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed

I need to do a regex capture/repalce on a file with content like the following.  While I'm okay at matching things, I'm having trouble doing a capture replace.

**I'd like to do the following:**

1. Capture  which will be different in every instance.
2. Add a new line before the copy  line that references the table name.

So, for example, `copy mytable(` would become `hello mytable\ncopy mytable(`.

---

**Sample Input**

```
copy tablename(
        preferredid= 'c0»',
        qid= 'c0»' with null(''),
        qpi= 'c0»',
        ptid= 'c0»' with null(''))...

into '/idata2/backup/core/eq.ingres'
```

Comment: So how does the sample output look like? `hello tablename\ncopy tablename`?

Comment: `s/^(?=copy tablename\()/hello mytable\n/` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
sed 's/^copy \([^(]*\)($/hello \1\ncopy \1(/'
```

Comment: +1 but you can simplify a bit: `sed 's/^copy \([^(]*\)($/hello \1\n&/'`

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -i -pe 's/^(?=copy (\w+)\()/hello $1\n/' file
```